# Where do I put my class files which are neither model, view nor controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails application. For one of my models, I created a specific class which will probably never be used anywhere else than in this specific model.

Where should I place the file corresponding to this class and its corresponding test file?

I currently placed it in /lib but since it will never be used elsewhere, I don't think that this is the right place for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a categorically correct answer to this question, because the class can be put in a few different locations that all make it available to the program and it's more a matter of organizational preference.

**tl;dr** lib is just fine.

#### Options:

1. models directory

   - If the class is related to the program domain, it may make sense to put it here. You could even namespace it and put it in a directory to get it out of the main dir and organize it relative to its function.
   - `app/models/user/password.rb` for `User::Password`
2. lib directory

   - If the class is orthogonal to the program domain, lib might be the right place. Domain specific stuff could also go here if it's clogging your models dir.
   - `lib/soap_client.rb`
3. in the file for the model that uses it

   - Probably not the best option, since it hides the classes existence (if you're looking at the directory structure)
   - For something like a custom `Exception` class or the like perhaps?

Comment: In the option 1, would I have to change my autoload_paths?

Comment: no, it should load everything in there, I believe. Only 1 way to find out though :)

Comment: @PierreMichard No, just as @jstim said Rails will autoload everything under the app/ directory. You can even have your own subdirectories, e.g. `app/decorators`, which will be included.

Answer (score 0):

As @jstim says there is no specific way.

But you can use the presenters or decorates for this

In app directory create a folder as presenters or decorators.

Create a file *some_file.eb*
In this you can create the class and use it in any controller you want.

app/presenters/some_file.eb

```
class ClassName
  def your_method
  end
end
```